# Help reading gene markers

Tags: human-biology, genetics, dna

I'm sorry if "gene markers" is not the correct word. An edit could be appreciated but I don't study in an English speaking country unfortunately.

Question overview:

In a family, there is a genetic, dominant disease. The father and a son is sick.
A gene marker analysis is performed with markers close to the assumed mutated gene on chromosome 11.

[image]

Marker D11S4088

[image]

Marker D11S1344

[image]

How do I read these and "What sort of markers are these"? I'm not sure what is going on here and I'm not sure what to search either due to language problems.

Thanks!

Comment: From what kind of experiment / machine etc do these graphs come from?

Comment: I have no idea. It doesn't say unfortunately. Could be a chromatogram?

Comment: @BjarniJóhannsson Those are not chromatograms from what I can see but rather a sort of counts per marker graph. "Genetic markers" is a better word. Do you know about linkage mapping? If not read this [wiki](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Genetic_linkage) and this [post](http://biology.stackexchange.com/questions/31099/markers-for-human-genetic-mapping/31104#31104), it should help.

Comment: I was thinking the same, or some sort of sequencing read coverage. I'm still not sure.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Just googling, they are SSLPs.  You do PCR, and the different alleles make different length amplicons.  Looks like there is some kind of artifact that causes some of the amplicons to have peaks that look 2, or 4, or 6 letters shorter than the true length.

So for the top marker, the 211 bp long allele is linked to the disease, and for the other one, the 118 bp allele is linked to the disease.